# Lightroom image looks different in the Print tab to Develop tab

Tags: lightroom

The photo is as I want it in the Develop screen, but when I click on the Print tab it's as if my colour changes (cropping seems to have stayed) are gone, and the preview in the Print tab looks like the original. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

[image: Develop]

[image: Print]

Comment: the "grey" part of the histogram has the same colour as the background in print mode. i'm not sure what that means, but it probably has something to do with color management. do you have soft proofing enabled?

Comment: You're right - I'm not sure if that's just coincidence though... I don't have soft proofing enabled, but when I do, in the Develop screen it looks the same, just with a white background.

If I show before and after in Develop mode, the "before" looks just like the Print preview see http://i.imgur.com/712bKcJ.jpg

Funnily enough, when I actually print it, it looks like in Develop mode - the wall is grey rather than browny